# Grab Number From Text And Add One With Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I am trying to just grab a number from this div, and it only contains this one number. Now once I grab it I would like to add one to it, but I can not get this to work. I am successfully grabbing the number, but when I add to it the number does not seem to work correctly.

Let me give you an example:

```
Div has the number 10 in it.
Jquery runs on it.
Div has the number 11 in it.
```

That is the expected, but instead, it changes the number to 1 after I add to it, and I do not know why.

Here is my code:

```
$(".postvotenumber").text(parseInt($(".postvotenumber").val()) + 1);
```

So this code is not adding one to the current number, but instead just making it one. How do I fix this? Thank You!

Comment: change .val() to .text()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jquery is a bit off try this

```
$(".postvotenumber").text(parseInt($(".postvotenumber").text()) + 1);
```

divs do not have a value, so the val function doesn't return anything. The text function returns what is in the div tag.

Comment: Thank you, I thought to grab the actual number you had to use `.val()`. Thank You again! :)

Comment: Can't accept the answer until after 10 minutes. By the way, just a little issue, and this is probably something else but... Anyhow the number is 4 lets say, another run and it says "5", and then it says "56", and then it says "5657". So my question is why is it just not adding on to the number?

Comment: it shouldn't, see http://jsfiddle.net/depperm/5j8Lzw0v/, my guess is your using a different jquery that is concatenating strings instead of adding after the first time, make sure to parseInt

Comment: Hmm, that is odd. Anyhow I will accept your answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: P.S. using Jquery **1.10.2**.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$(".postvotenumber").text((parseInt($(".postvotenumber").text()) + 1));
```

.val is used for inputs and text area's mostly.  For a div you'll need to get the text via the .text, and set it with .text() also.